# Pandas Time Grouper: Custom Ranges

Tags: python, pandas

Conditional on a `datetime` index, `pd.TimeGrouper("AS")` groups my data by calendar years. There is a [variety of useful offsets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) shipped with `pandas` - but what if I want my own one?

For example, what if I'd like to group by 2-year periods, or 16 months? How would I approach that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that's in the next section on [combining offsets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#combining-aliases), eg:

```
In [40]: rng = date_range('1/1/2015', periods=365, freq='D')
In [41]: d = Series(range(0, len(rng)), index=rng)
```

Group by month

```
In [42]: d.groupby(TimeGrouper('MS')).first()
Out[42]:
2015-01-01      1
2015-02-01     32
2015-03-01     60
2015-04-01     91
2015-05-01    121
2015-06-01    152
2015-07-01    182
2015-08-01    213
2015-09-01    244
2015-10-01    274
2015-11-01    305
2015-12-01    335
Freq: MS, dtype: int64
```

3 months:

```
In [43]: d.groupby(TimeGrouper('3MS')).first()
Out[43]:
2015-01-01      1
2015-04-01     91
2015-07-01    182
2015-10-01    274
Freq: 3MS, dtype: int64
```

So two years could be `2AS`, 16 months could be `16MS`